# Using PHP variables with ADODB

Tags: php, adodb, oxid

I am trying to do a SQL query with ADODB, which is used in the OXID framework.

```
$database = oxDb::getDb();
$sql = 'SELECT oxobjectid FROM oxobject2discount WHERE oxdiscountid = '.$oxdiscountid;
$resultado = $database->execute($sql);
```

This will always throw and exception error. I know you can use the function `Prepare` with ADODB to sanitize the statement and get ready to use it. However I am unable to call it in Oxid, it seems.

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: what is value of `$oxdiscountid` ?

Comment: A bunch of characters taken from a database (char32). I will try forcing $sql into a string.

Comment: This worked. You should delete the semicolon after $oxdiscountid but that is obviously a typo. Also post it as an answer so I can check it as answered.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that you could also use the OXID Framework. Just instantiate `oxbase`, call `init` with the table name. Then you can build a select string with `buildSelectString` and assign the record with `assignRecord`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"` quotes

```
$sql = 'SELECT oxobjectid FROM oxobject2discount WHERE oxdiscountid = "'.$oxdiscountid;.'"';
```